# Show that u is a limit point for the set.

Tags: analysis

Let $a_1, a_2, a_3$,.... be a sequence so that $a_1<a_2<a_3<...$ and so that the sequence is bounded. (The set of points is bounded.) Let $u$ denote the least upper bound of ${[a_n]}$ from n=1 to infinity. Show that $u$ is a limit point of the set of points  ${[a_n]}$ from n=1 to infinity.

Since $u$ is the least upper bound and I want to prove that u is the limit point,  I know need to prove that $u$ is not in the set. I just am unsure of how to begin.

Let M= ${[a_n]}$ from n=1 to infinity.

First, I will assume that $u\in M$. (Proving by contradiction.)

I also know that I want to show that the points in the set "limit" to $u$, I'm just struggling.

Comment: You know that the sequence is bounded. So $a_n \leq M$ fore some $M \in \mathbb{R}$. Also we know that $u = \sup a_n$. So what doe s that mean?

Comment: Hint: What's the definition of limit point?

Comment: @CarlLove The definition of a limit point: u is a limit point of M if (a,b) is a segment containing u, then (a,b) contains a point of M distinct from P.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that $u$ is not in the set, assume the opposite. Then $u = a_n$ for some $n$. Then $u < a_{n+1}$. So $u$ is not an upper bound. Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *definition* of limit point and supremum!

For $u=\sup_n a_n$, it means that this is the smallest upper bound of the sequence.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary, then the interval $(u-\varepsilon,u+\varepsilon)$ must contain elements of the sequence $a_n$, because otherwise $u-\varepsilon$ would be a *smaller* upper bound.

Comment: I understand what the supremum and limit point definitions are. Could you give any insight in how to prove that u i not in the set?

Comment: See Carl Love's answer about that.